# MicroService path /api/v1/ or /v1/api/

Tags: java, microservices, grizzly

I'm building a MicroSerive and I was planning to publish services using this URI naming convention:

```
https://host:port/api/v1/service1
https://host:port/api/v1/service2
https://host:port/api/v2/service1
https://host:port/api/v2/service2
```

But I've also seen URIs named like this (ie vx and api 'swapped'):

```
https://host:port/v1/api/service1
https://host:port/v1/api/service2
https://host:port/v2/api/service1
https://host:port/v2/api/service2
```

In my opinion, the first approach is better. Are there any reasons to go for the second approach?

Comment: Don't do either. Ideally don't version your service at all, and if you absolutely must, use `Content-Type`.

Comment: @chrylis: So only https://host:port/api/service1 (I need the root for static (swagger) content)? Any well known examples where the Content-Type approach is used?

Comment: Why not make RESTFUL clients/server?

Comment: This is for JSON/REST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it doesn't matter

But within an overall REST approach the URL should be easily readable and comprehensible by a humain.

using your first approach is the correct form as it's easily readable as

```
The Api of Version 1 that exposes ...
```